# Connect to an Access database in Java using NetBeans

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, jdbc-odbc

How do I connect to an Access database in Java?

I have done like this:

```
package inspection.management.system;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Fuhans
 */

public class Database 
{
    public static void DatabaseConnectivity()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "d:\\program files\\project\\program\\inspection management system\\db1.accdb";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            System.out.println("Connection Successful");
            InfoBox.ShowMessageBox("Connection Successful!", "Success");
        } 

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Got an exception!");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

            InfoBox.ShowMessageBox("Got an Exception!", "Error");
            InfoBox.ShowMessageBox(e.getMessage(), "Error");
        }
    }
}

if (_textField1.equals("Fuhans") && _passwordField1.equals("Xavega"))
        {
            Sound.PlaySound(1);
            InfoBox.ShowMessageBox("Successfully Login!", "Success");
            Database.DatabaseConnectivity();
        }
```

When i successfully login, it gave me error on database:

[image]

What have i done wrong?

Comment: Did you create the data source using the ODBC Administrator app?

Comment: not, in the ODBC Administrator app, i don't have Ms access Driver, i just have SQL Driver. But right now for this app, i am using Ms Access.

Comment: So if there is no Access ODBC driver installed, how do you expect to connect to an Access db then?

Comment: in c#, i just connect it through code, no need to set all the things, just create a database and access it through code. But now i am using Java and i don't know how to connect my application in java to the database. Could you please help me sir?

Answer (score 2):

> in the ODBC Administrator app, i don't have Ms access Driver, i just have SQL Driver.

Now that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java (since Java 8) you should consider using the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver. It is a pure Java implementation so it works on non-Windows platforms, too.

For more information see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a DSN(Data Source Name) first.

In control panel, if there is no drivers for accessing even though you have installed then there is a possibility that you may not getting odbcad32.exe file path. **Choose your path from this, and then right click Data Sources(ODBC)[where you are creating DSN], and paste one of following path there.**

1. The 32-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located at:

   %WinDir%\Windows\SysWoW64
2. The 64-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located at:

   %WinDir%\Windows\System32

and while accessing, do like this:

```
String url = "jdbc:odbc:dsn_name";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

change the statement:

```
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "d:\\program files\\project\\program\\inspection management system\\db1.accdb";
```

to:

```
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C://program files//project//program//inspection management system//db1.accdb";
```