# cannot find symbol executeQuery

Tags: java, netbeans, database-connection

I'm new to Netbeans and now trying to make JDBC connectivity. I want to connect a MS Access database `mis.accdb` with my java file `ShowData.java`. The contents of `ShowData.java`

```
import java.beans.Statement;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ShowData extends HttpServlet
{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException
{
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
Connection con=null;
Statement st=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
try{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    try 
    {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mis");
    } catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(ShowData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
st=(Statement) con.createStatement();
rs=st.executeQuery("select * from student");
out.println("<table border='1'><tr><th>Student ID</th><th>Student Name</th><th>Branch</th></tr>");
while(rs.next())
{
int sid=rs.getInt("StudId");
String snm=rs.getString("StudName");
String br=rs.getString("Branch");
out.println("<tr>");
out.println("<td>"+sid+"</td>");
out.println("<td>"+snm+"</td>");
out.println("<td>"+br+"</td>");
}
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
{
out.println("Driver Loading Failed...");
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
out.println("Please Check SQL Query...");
}
}
}
```

This code worked initially without Netbeans IDE and now when i tried to implement it in IDE, it shows me an error on the line `rs=st.executeQuery("select * from student");` as

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method executeQuery(String)
location: variable st of type Statement
```

Please help me solve this issue and also guide me as to how to connect to the above specified MS Access Database `mis.accdb`in Netbeans. Thanks

Comment: You are going to need a jdbc driver for this, try looking at this post it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007353/connect-to-an-access-database-in-java-using-netbeans

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked...!!

Answer (score 3):

The import `java.beans.Statement` is not the correct one.  You probably meant `java.sql.Statement`.

After that change you can probably also remove the cast in this line:

```
st=(Statement) con.createStatement();
```

Comment: Tried this. Still no output. Just a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I also faced
This helped me solve it

I used

```
PreparedStatement st = null;

st = con.prepareStatement("THE QUERY");

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
```

all this in the same event/function